# Does CDI work for regular Java application?

Tags: java, cdi

I have simple maven project with three classes.  In my `META-INF` I have my empty `beans.xml`.  Everytime I run my `Main.java` I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at hom.World.helloWorld(World.java:12)
at hom.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish is way out of scope of what CDI is suppose to do?

Hello.java

```
package hom;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;

@Default
public class Hello {
   public String hello() {
      return "Hello ";
   }
}
```

World.java

```
package hom;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Default;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Default
public class World {
   @Inject
   Hello hello;

   public String helloWorld() {
      return hello.hello() + "World!";
   }
}
```

Main.java

```
package hom;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      World helloWorld = new World();
      System.out.println(helloWord.helloWorld());
   }
}
```

Comment: You still need some sort of container. Spring is a good default choice, especially with Spring Boot.

Comment: You can use CDI for desktop applications using Weld, see: http://aprogrammersguidetothegalaxy.blogspot.co.il/2010/08/simple-java-se-application-with-weld.html

Comment: @chrylis What if I want to use this as a utility jar for my web application?  Do I still need a container?

Comment: This is one of many reasons that field injection is a bad pattern. If you use constructor injection instead, you can still put `@Inject` on the constructor, but you can easily use it outside a container by specifically passing in the dependencies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to use CDI in a standalone application.

```
Weld weld = new Weld();
WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
World helloWorld = container.instance().select(World.class).get();
System.out.println(helloWorld.helloWorld());
weld.shutdown();
```

You will also need the weld-se dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

See also [Weld documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#_java_se) on the subject.

Comment: This helped lead me in the right direction and found a good tutorial.  
  [http://randling.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cdi-in-java-se/](http://randling.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/cdi-in-java-se/)

Comment: Link to Weld documentation is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The following example works for CDI 2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Dependency is the same.

```
package com.zetcode;

import com.zetcode.provider.HelloMessageProvider;
import com.zetcode.renderer.ConsoleMessageRenderer;
import com.zetcode.renderer.MessageRenderer;

import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainer;
import javax.enterprise.inject.se.SeContainerInitializer;

public class CdiSimple {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SeContainerInitializer initializer = SeContainerInitializer.newInstance();

        try (SeContainer container = initializer.disableDiscovery()
                .addBeanClasses(HelloMessageProvider.class, ConsoleMessageRenderer.class).initialize()) {

            MessageRenderer messageRenderer = container.select(ConsoleMessageRenderer.class).get();
            messageRenderer.render();
        }
    }
}
```

We use `SeContainerInitializer` and `SeContainer` to set up CDI on Java SE.

```
package com.zetcode.provider;

public interface MessageProvider {

    String getMessage();
}
```

This is `MessageProvider`.

```
package com.zetcode.provider;

public class HelloMessageProvider implements MessageProvider {

    public String getMessage() {

        return "Hello there";
    }
}
```

This is `HelloMessageProvider`.

```
package com.zetcode.renderer;

public interface MessageRenderer {

    void render();
}
```

This is `MessageRenderer`.

```
package com.zetcode.renderer;

import com.zetcode.provider.MessageProvider;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class ConsoleMessageRenderer implements MessageRenderer {

    @Inject
    private MessageProvider messageProvider;

    public void render() {

        var message = messageProvider.getMessage();

        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

And finally, this is `ConsoleMessageRenderer`.