# Trying to instantiate a bean with the CDI from a running webapplication

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I have a jar that contains a @Stateless class defined like

```
 @Stateless 
 public class TestBean() {
     @Inject 
     AnotherBean bean2;
     public String getThis() {
      return bean2.getAString();   
     }
 }
```

A webapplication (with a dependency on this jar) running on wildfly 10.1.0 would like to instantiate this bean and use its methods. The webapplication calling method might be a rest endpoint (called by some other webapplication) or just a regular java method.

What is the best way to instantiate TestBean? I have tried several solutions none of which works.

For example this one

[Building a CDI 2 standalone](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/cdi/building-a-cdi-2-standalone-java-application)

and this one

[Does CDI work for regular Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396614/does-cdi-work-for-regular-java-application)

I am new to the CDI and how it works, I am wondering if this is explained well somewhere?

Comment: Does it have a `beans.xml` file?

Comment: Yes it does have a beans.xml set to scan all beans.

Answer (score 0):

Its not really clear what your question is, but if you have JAX-RS resource, in the WAR file, then this should just work

```
@Path("/somePath")
@RequestScoped
public class SomeResource {
    @Inject
    private TestBean testBean;
    @GET
    public String doGet() {
        return testBean.getThis();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is whether there is a way of instantiating SomeResource and call doGet without being a REST endpoint. Just a plain API java method.